# How to protect a cheap RF amplifier from spontaneously dying?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, rf, protection

I've bought a few RF amplifiers based on the SPF5189z LNA chip. These have decent performance for their price but there is a common issue where they just kinda die from pretty much any reason. I've looked for solutions online, people have had these die even when running from a proper regulated, current-limited supply (probably when connecting/disconnecting). I personally lost two already.

Surprisingly enough, I haven't really found any modifications online that could be done to the amplifier board to strengthen it. While I couldn't find a circuit schematic specific to the production boards, it seems to be identical to the 1900 MHz evaluation board schematic from the datasheet, so I am assuming the component values are similar;

[image]

[image]

I hope I have picked the right category to ask this question; I have this rather sensitive semiconductor component with a seemingly lacking circuit and I am looking for ways to improve its chances of surviving being connected to a 5V power bank (which in itself should be well regulated but apparently not well enough for this LNA). The supply voltage recommended by the datasheet is 5V however it should be able to take some voltage drop, so perhaps there is some common voltage/current regulation IC that I could put between the board and the power supply that could help?

There already are two capacitors on the supply lines by default, I believe one has a lower and the other a higher value as to ensure their combined performance over different frequencies. Maybe I should add a third, higher-value capacitor to smooth out the voltage drop when the supply is disconnected? And/or an inductor to dampen the current spike when connected? I've had some devices that had a beefier capacitor on the supply lines and they caused USB supplies to shut down as that "protection" capacitor drew too much current, so I'm not sure if adding one here would be a good solution.

I've seen a few suggestions from people about simply adding a current limiting resistor in series with the supply as apparently an amplifier like this can sometimes draw more current than it should, but in this case I don't know how to select the proper value for the resistor (also while I've seen *suggestions* I don't remember ever seeing anyone actually doing it).

The datasheet is here: https://www.qorvo.com/products/d/da001910. TL;DR: it runs on 5V, draws about 90mA nominally with an absolute max of 120 mA.

Any tips on this would be greatly appreciated, as even though the amplifiers are cheap I wouldn't want to be constantly buying new ones while building up a stockpile of dead boards.

Comment: Buy from the original supplier of the demo board. Don't buy cheap copies from unregulated sources that don't have quality systems in place. Try changing the chip for one from the original chip manufacturer. No pro EE would risk cheap copies from a source with no credentials.

Comment: Doesn’t look like there is much ESD protection on that board. What is connected to RFout?

Comment: It sounds like the amp could be not unconditionally stable and could start oscillating if you don't have a proper source/load impedance attached. The amp will exhibit large voltage excursions due to oscillation which can break down device junctions or draw enough current to fry the device. I'm not sure if this is your specific problem though. Since it's a MMIC, there's not really much of a solution, other than ensuring you power off the device before changing any connections, and always ensuring you have a sources/load attached before powering it on.

Answer (score 2):

**Power supply:**

I think part of the answer to your problem lies in the type of power supply you are using. Using a power bank is a bad idea, firstly the voltage supplied isn't clean with lots of oscillations. That is for the established state.
During turn on, power bank use boost converter /buck converter if the cells are in series inside the bank. This kind of switched supply generally generate spikes during turn on. Which can cause the voltage to increase over the target (here 5V).
I've seen good Analog devices buck converter going over 6.2V for a 5V target. These repeated expositions to such voltage will cause harm to the RF amplifier, if they exceed the recommended operating conditions.

To correct this you could use a LDO, the LDO doesn't have those switching, as the answer is linear, increase over the target voltage is unlikely.

**Decoupling / power supply filtration**

The decoupling on your board looks correct to me, capacitor such as 1uF or 10uF could be added to create an even better filter.

**Other**

Putting a series resistor will create non linearity in the amplifier response. Attenuating the higher end / more powerful signal more than the less powerful.

*What are you driving the amplifier with ?*
*What are you driving with the amplifier ?*

I recently bought a module from AliExpress which uses the component giving you trouble:
https://a.aliexpress.com/_uGhKM7
This module is very good, and still works after a few hour of uses. You could get inspiration from here.
They use a LDO to supply the SPF5189.

Answer (score 0):

How clean is your power supply?
What are you driving it with, and is your drive power within spec at ALL times?
What are you loading it with (And is the load the designed impedance including at harmonics)?

It could be power supply shenanigans, but I would almost bet that gate overdrive is more likely, pHEMETs are not known for robust gate structures and as little as 3dB of gate overdrive might do for it.

Does your RF source look like 50 ohms including way outside whatever band you are interested in? The thing might be honking due to the source going high Z out of band.

These are static sensitive devices, are you taking appropriate ESD measures?